# Create a custom wordpress plugin than can be called directly like mydomain.com/mytemplate.php?id=xx

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to create a template, which is done by now, but i want to call it directly without have to create any page that use my file as the template.
The idea was having a specific template to show some custom information and call it like: http://mydomain.com/mycustomtemplate.php?id=7777

I try to call it like it is and doesn't work... says file or directoy not found

Anyone has a sugestion or been through this?

Thanks i advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to elaborate a little more on this.  Is the idea to have a custom template for only certain pages?

Wordpress themes (or templates as you are reffing to them as) don't work in the manner that you are referring to:

http://mydomain.com/mycustomtemplate.php?id=7777

The link above refers to a file outside of the whole Wordpress Theme hierarchy.

Please be more clear on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a template, but no file that actually uses it? You'd need some hack up Wordpress's standard RewriteRules to detect a URL that should use your template and redirect the request somewhere that is aware of the template.

You're basically saying "I want to have a car, but I don't want to actually HAVE a car, how can I have a car?"

Comment: That's exacly it. I mean... i can create a Page and use my template and then it will redirect correctly... but I thought i could achieve this more easily.... I'm gonna do some research in the rewriterules...